# How to display only one error if multiple errors occur?

Tags: php, error-handling

So, I have this api on my website that will sometimes get HTTP errors due to the the site I'm grabbing data from having some downtime. I was wondering how I could only display only one error if multiple errors occur using a custom error handler?

Here's my current code:

```
function Error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  echo "ERROR";
  error_log($errstr . " - on line " . $errline);
}
set_error_handler("Error");
```

Comment: Is that code called in a loop? If so set or return a variable and only call the function if the variable or whatever is not set. Hard to advise without knowing how the function is implemented

Comment: @James yes, it's called in a loop. Thanks! I didn't think of that.

Comment: @James I tried that, but it couldn't seem to get the variable for some reason & displayed this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: isError`

Comment: Edit your question to show the loop code, with your new thing too. Gotta be something simple :)

Comment: @James there's no where in my code where it loops... php calls my error function each time there's an error, I have no control over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. `die()` prevents the function from being called again. But this also means if there's another error then it wouldn't be logged since the function would only be called once.

```
function Error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo "ERROR";
    error_log($errstr . " - on line " . $errline);
    die();
}
set_error_handler("Error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all your errors inside an array and then just display the first error in the array.

Comment: This is a bit inefficient though. Why use an array (multiple values) when all you want is 1 value?

Comment: Wait, the error function is called in a loop... So it will display the 1st error in the array multiple times

Comment: @Fallen So then exit the loop after you display the error.

Comment: I have no control on how much times my error function is called, php calls it each time there's an error.

Comment: @Fallen Have a look at James answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have no control over it the best way is not really going to be clean - i.e. there are likely better ways with cleaner code overall.

I don't know much about the rest of your code, but you need to wrap this entire thing in a check to see if there is an error. I don't know where the vars etc come from, but presume PHP standard, e.g.

```
if (!empty($errno)) {
    function Error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        error_log($errstr . " - on line " . $errline);
    }
    set_error_handler("Error");

    if (empty($errorWasDisplayed)) {
        $errorWasDisplayed = true;
        echo "whatever your error message is";
    }
}
```

It'll always be the first error, but if you need a specific one then you just simply need to adjust the condition to factor that in.

You can return a value from your function if needed to show in the error message.

Comment: The problem with your code is that it'll echo even if no error occurs

Comment: Hmm, I'm working a bit blind to be honest as all I see is a function and an error message. You can't show me the loop nor other code. One sec...

Comment: Actually, won't it also always call the function and try to log things? If not then the code I added will be fine, as you stated in another comment "*php calls it each time there's an error.*" If it's determined elsewhere if there's an error then the above is fine, otherwise maybe the function and my code needs to be in a sanity check?

Comment: yes & for some reason it can't get variables outside of the function, I don't know why

Comment: wait, no it won't always call the function. php only calls the function if there's a error (sorry I miss read)

Comment: Hmm not sure how that works, how does PHP know to call that function only when there's been an error? Not sure what you need without seeing the rest of your code. Perhaps the above works. Alternatively you could just wrap the block I made in the `if ($errno)` alternatively return a variable from the function so you know an error was set and use that to output an error if that var and the one set inside the condition are both set